# How to "fix" localversion in Kernel menuconfig?

Tags: arm, embedded, kernel

I'm building Kernel for my embedded ARM-based system (system is a ARM7 VARISCITE DART6UL).
Since I need to build Kernel appending my local version to it, I read it's possible to edit (using make menuconfig) the right local version I need, writing in General setup->"Local version - append to kernel release".
Commands I execute to edit .config kernel are the following:

`make mrproper
make imx6ul-var-dart_defconfig
make menuconfig`

My question is: why my kernel release that I appended in the graphical kernel menu config file doesn't still remain saved?
Everytime I enter in menuconfig it disappear: Is there a way to fixed it, avoiding the need to rewrite each time?

Regards

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy back the .config file to arch/arm/configs/imx6ul-var-dart_defconfig

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer.